# Parallel Execution not working in Selenium key word driven automation framework

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have keyword driven automation framework in Selenium.

At the  run-time i am creating testng suite.xml which includes all method names(the testcases which are marked as Yes in Test Suite.xls), parallel=methods, thread-count-2 and then testng.xml is executed.

Although two browser instance is opened, only one test script is executed. Other browser instance wait till first script is executed and then second script is executed.

It would be great if some one can help me on this or provide alternative solution to implement parallel execution in key-word driven framework.

Comment: Actually executing methods in two different browser instances is not suggested since it may have dependencies but you can post your code here and show what exactly you wrote

Answer (score 0):

Used `Threadable Webdriver` which creates browser instances on parallel threads and executed the scripts.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with selenium grid to execute the script in parallel. It may help you.

Comment: Thats for multiple machines. For single machine you don't need grid

Comment: we can use it single machine as well. you have run hub and node on same mahcine. then the scripts will execute in parallel otherwise switching between two instances of browsers is not able to handled by testng. you can try it and let me know.

Comment: Yes its true but we dont need in this case